# What is for, for?

Tags: java, for-loop

I would like to ask you guys a question. You see, I know what a for-loop is for but can someone please maybe explain how one works, just to help me get my head around it, an example is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

Now obviously that will just print Hello 10 times into the console but that's besides the point, I want to know how the for-loop works.

Sorry if i have confused anyone asking this - Shaun

Comment: #1 resource: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Iteration is a central concept to computer programming. How would you examine a list of ten million items, for example?

Comment: @JustinSatyr: Have a look at Ted Hopp's answer, below.

Comment: @GregS - I think OP is asking about the semantics of the `for` construct in Java, not about iteration as a concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The for Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

> The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>      statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i love how simple java is when you know it haha :D

Answer (score 10):

The `for` loop in your example is more or less equivalent to this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    i++;
}
```

The only difference is that with your `for` loop, the variable `i` exists only within the scope of the loop.

Every `for` loop can be transformed into a `while` loop using this same pattern.

```
for (init; test; continuation) {
    // loop body
}
```

becomes:

```
init;
while (test) {
    // loop body
    continuation;
}
```

Again, the only difference will be with the scope of any variables declared in `init`.

Comment: It's not the ***only*** difference. If in the for loop you use `continue;`, i will be incremented, whereas in the while "equivalent" it will not.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan - Thanks for pointing this out. The `continue` statement violates the rules of [structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). (So do `return`, `throws`, and `break`.) It is hard to model it with a `while` loop. When I used "only", I had in mind OP's specific example; I should have been more careful in my word choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how it is set up:

`for (a; b; c)`

"A" is something that is done at the beginning of the loop. It can actually be left out if necessary, like this:

`for (; b; c)`

"B" must be a true or false statement (like i<10, it either is or it isn't). Once "b" is no longer true, the loop stops.

"C" is something that is done at the end of the loop.

Comment: Actually, any or all of `a`, `b`, and `c` can be left out of a `for` loop.

Comment: I guess you're right, but wouldn't leaving out `b` make it infinite?

Comment: If you leave out `b`, then it is indeed an infinite loop. The only ways out are `break`, `return` or throwing an exception.